# My session get automatically expired even the application is active

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have Kept `sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30"`  in `web.config` file. After 30 minutes even though my session is active it gets expired. My requirement is session gets expired if the session is inactive about 30 minutes. If it is active the process need to continue.  I am using asp.net.

```
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
Session.RemoveAll();

if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie currentUserCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("ASP.NET_SessionId");
    currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
    currentUserCookie.Value = null;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie);
}

if (Request.Cookies["AuthToken"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie currentUserCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["AuthToken"];
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Remove("AuthToken");
    currentUserCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
    currentUserCookie.Value = null;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(currentUserCookie);
}
```

Comment: Where you have this code and why you are expiring cookies related to session?

Comment: its in aspx.cs file

Comment: I mean is it in some button click event or page load etc

Comment: its not in button click... it gets automatically expires after 30 min..